How to config wdio.config.js in Webdriverio using javascript
have a good day for you. I am studying about automated testing by javascript, i meet a problem about hook , i have find many source, but i can not fix the error. If i remove "const expect = require('chai').expect" my code will run successfully. I don't know why the error appear.
this is my code
const loginPage = require("../loginPage.js");
const loginData = require("../Test_Data/testLogin.json"); 
const expect = require('chai').expect

describe('API Command', function() {
    let pageUrl = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login";
    
    before("Refresh Page", async function(){
        await browser.url(pageUrl);
        await browser.pause(3000);
    })

    afterEach("after Text", async function() {
        await browser.refresh();
    });

    it('loginForm with incorrect', async () => {
        const loginPageInstance = new loginPage();
        const expectedLoginPageTitle = "Login Page";
        const actualLoginPagetitle = await loginPageInstance.getTitle();

        expect(actualLoginPagetitle).to.equal(expectedLoginPageTitle);
    });
});

this is my error
 Error:  Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialized.
`browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.
Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.

Thank you very much everyone!
